# How to set variable from use object in sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

I have plain use class which contains one method that returns complex bean with a lot of setters/getters. Lets name it `SomeUse`. Given sightly file:

```
<sly data-sly-use.someUse="com.mycompany.SomeUse">
  ${someUse.data.firstProperty}
  <div>
    ${someUse.data.secondProperty}
  </div>
  <!-- ...and so on -->
</sly>
```

So the point is I don't want to look at `someUse.data` getting. Instead of it I **would** do something like this:

```
<sly data-sly-use.someUse="com.mycompany.SomeUse" data-sly-use.data=${someUse.data}>
  ${data.firstProperty}
  <div>
    ${data.secondProperty}
  </div>
  <!-- ...and so on -->
</sly>
```

I can't do this way though. Is there any alternative to achieve such result? Thanks a lot!

Comment: why is java tagged ?

Comment: Removed :) Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer is to:

```
<sly data-sly-test.varName="${data.firstProperty}"></sly>
<div> ${varName.secondProperty} </div>
```

Creating a variable through empty `data-sly-test` attribute make it accessible after a tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can set variables for use in a WCMUse class with the following syntax:

```
<sly data-sly-use.someUse="${ 'com.mycompany.SomeUse' @ page=currentPage }">
```

and retrieve the `page` variable from your WCMUse class's `activate()` method like this:

```
Page page = get("page", Page.class);
```

For a working example, check out [this Sightly script](https://github.com/blefebvre/aem-phonegap-kitchen-sink/blob/e757f512812414cfc9d016cd244ea2d52e79f07c/content-dev/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/brucelefebvre/kitchen-sink/components/ng-ionic-page/menu.html#L1) and [this WCMUse class](https://github.com/blefebvre/aem-phonegap-kitchen-sink/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/brucelefebvre/wcm/PageHelper.java#L29).

Comment: Documentation can be found here : https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/use-api-in-java.html#Passing Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `data-sly-use.data=${someUse.data}`
use `data-sly-test.data="${someUse.data}"`.
Then you will be able to get the property like

```
${data.firstProperty}
  <div>
    ${data.secondProperty}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set in DOM elements

```
<div id="elementId" data-sly-test.vehicle="${model.vehicle}">
    <p>${vehicle.name}</p>
     <p>${vehicle.type}</p>
</div>
```